# How to order a list of maps in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm supposed to order a list of maps and I've tried everything I can think of, no breakthrough.

Here's my code:

```
var orgs = [
  {"name": "Google", "category": "Search Engine"},
  {"name": "Facebook", "category": "Social Media"},
  {"name": "Adidas", "category": "Sports"}
];
```

I want to sort this list by name. I tried using this code:

```
  orgs.sort((i, j) => i.name.compareTo(j.name)); //I get an error that name is not defined. only works with classes
```

But I get an error that name is not defined. What am I doing wrong? Or is there another approach i can try? Please assist

By the way, its important that orgs is strictly a list, not anything else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is defining the array as a list of maps

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> orgs = [
  {"name": "Google", "category": "Search Engine"},
  {"name": "Facebook", "category": "Social Media"},
  {"name": "Adidas", "category": "Sports"}
];
```

This way it can then be sorted :

```
orgs.sort((a, b) => a["name"].compareTo(b["name"]));
```

The answer:

```
[{name: Adidas, category: Sports}, 
{name: Facebook, category: Social Media}, 
{name: Google, category: Search Engine}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```
 orgs.sort((i, j) => i["name"]!.compareTo(j["name"]!));
```

P.S Make sure the key "name" is always present in the objects.

Comment: I get an error that "compareTo" is not defined for type object

Answer (score 0):

Your sort is comparing maps, so it needs to use the key syntax.

```
orgs.sort((i, j) => i['name']?.compareTo(j['name'] ?? "") ?? 1);
```

Comment: I get an error that "compareTo" is not defined for type object

Comment: You can change your definition of orgs to be `Map<String, String> orgs = ...` to give it a concrete type.

Comment: Thank you. i figured it out. I'm supposed to define it as `List<Map<String, dynamic>> orgs = ...`